# AutoMapper mapping lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, automapper

Here is my scenario:

```
public class Dto {
    public string PrimaryId { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryId { get; set; }
    public DtoType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Record {
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper configuration

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Dto, Record>()
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.RowKey, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.SecondaryId))
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.PartitionKey, op => op.MapFrom(src => $"{src.PrimaryId}.{src.Type}"));
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.Type));
                cfg.CreateMap<Record, Dto>()
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.SecondaryId, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.RowKey))
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.PrimaryId, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.PartitionKey.Split('.')[0]))
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.Type);
            });
mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Lambda expression mapping

```
Expression<Func<Dto, bool>> predicate;
var expression = _mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Record, bool>>>(predicate);
```

I would assume that I can simply query this scenario by:

```
Expression<Func<Dto, bool>> predicate = x => x.PrimaryId == "A" && x.Type == DtoType.SomeType
```

But that above query doesn't work. I don't fully understand the magic that happens behind expression translation in AutoMapper.

EDIT* adding error message for more detail:

```
Rewriting child expression from type 'DtoType' to type 'System.Int32' is not allowed, because it would change the meaning of the operation. If this is intentional, override 'VisitUnary' and change it to allow this rewrite.
```

Comment: `x.Type` is a `DtoType`... why would you be comparing that to an integer?

Comment: @JeffMercado my mistake, I changed the example. It is not what is in code, I just quickly wrote it down in this question as a hypothetical example.